# I am writing a function in java that puts the first char in the third place and it repeats every three char as long as the word is

Tags: java

Following is the function that I have, it gives me desired result but I wanted to know if there is other way to approach this? May be with nested for loop?

```
public class RandomFunctionalities2 {
    public String mixWords(String firstWord, String secondWord) {
        return firstWord+secondWord;
    }

    public String switcheroo(String word) {
        if (word.length() < 3) {
            return word;
        }
        StringBuilder c = new StringBuilder();
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 3 * (word.length() / 3); i+=3)
            c.append(word.substring(i + 1, i + 3) + word.charAt(i));

        c.append(word.substring(i));
        return c.toString();
    }
}
```

TEST*

```
    public class testingRandomFunctionalities2 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            RandomFunctionalities2 rf1 = new RandomFunctionalities2();
            
    
            System.out.println(rf1.switcheroo("george"));
            System.out.println(rf1.switcheroo("you"));
        }
    }
```

TEST RESULT*

```
eogger
ouy

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: FYI, `char`/`Character` breaks with most characters. I suggest using [code points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be to split your input at every 3rd char and join back after swaping first and third chars of each substring:

```
public String switcheroo2(String word) {
    String[] split = word.split("(?<=\\G...)");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s : split){
        if(s.length() > 2){
            sb.append(s.substring(1)).append(s.charAt(0));
        }
        else {
            sb.append(s);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

You could save somemore lines using Pattern class and streams by doing something like:

```
public String switcheroo3(String word) {
    UnaryOperator<String> op = str -> str.length() < 3 ? str : str.substring(1) + str.charAt(0);
    return Pattern.compile("(?<=\\G...)")
                    .splitAsStream(word).map(op::apply)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```